# Twig json encode and comma's

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, twig

I have a Twig array like this:

```
var settings = JSON.parse('{{ theme | json_encode | raw }}');
```

For example as a result I get this:

```
var settings = JSON.parse('{"text_color":"#444444","company_info":"my company profile with a comma's"}');
```

What happens now is that when somebody write at company profile something with a comma or any other character the complete script breaks.

Example's:
- 'something'
- thing's
- awesome;

Is there a way to "accept" these special characters? I thought encode would read past those characters?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [json_encode TWIG Function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html#arguments) accept as agumets a bitmask of [json_encode options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php). As example:

```
{{ data|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}
```

Seem you are looking for the `JSON_HEX_APOS` constant

So try this:

```
var settings = JSON.parse('{{ theme | json_encode(constant('JSON_HEX_APOS')) | raw }}');
```

Hope this help

Comment: This really seems to work!! Jeeey... Just for my info: This doesn't work when somebody write's double quotes, right? So instead of `'something'` `"something"`

Comment: Hi @Meules the `"` are managed by the `JSON_HEX_QUOT` constant. I suppose you can combine the two constants in and or statement. You can try, let me know!